# How to pass arguments/parameters to mocha tests invoked via Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, integration-testing

I have a Gruntfile.js through which i'm invoking mochaTest using grunt-mocha-test module. I can pass an argument/parameter to the gruntTask from command line but i'm struggling to pass the same parameter into the spec file running via the above module. The code looks like below,

```
mochaTest: {
  test: {
    options: {
      reporter: 'spec',
      quiet: false,
      clearRequireCache: false,
      clearCacheFilter: (key) => true,
      noFail: false
    },
    src: [
          'test/createSpec.js'
         ]
  }
}
```

Task is registered like below,

```
grunt.registerTask('e2etest', function(scope) {
  console.log(scope); // logs user/session based on the parameter passed
  grunt.task.run('mochaTest');
});
// Above task is invoked like,
grunt e2etest:user
(or)
grunt e2etest:session
```

I need to pass this value (user/session) into mochaTest so it can be accessed inside the spec file. Fundamentally the aim is to run the createSpec.js file both for user and session, this values is parametrized inside the spec file and based on the value passed the suite would run.

Is there a possibility to do this? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize nodes [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to read the argument (i.e. `user` or `session`) from within the file named `createSpec.js`.

To better understand how, follow these steps:

1. At the top of `createSpec.js` add the following line of code:

   ```js
   console.log(process.argv);
   ```
2. Then run `grunt e2etest:user` via your CLI and you should see the following logged to your console:

   > `[ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/grunt', 'e2etest:user' ]`

   *Note: the information you want is positioned at index two of the array.*
3. Now, delete the line we just added which reads `console.log(process.argv);` from `createSpec.js`.

---

**createSpec.js**

So, the steps above (1-3) illustrated that the arguments (`user` or `session`) can be accessed in `createSpec.js` utilizing `process.argv`. In which case you could do something like the following inside `createSpec.js`.

```js
const argument = process.argv[2].split(':').pop();

if (argument === 'user') {
  // Run `user` specific tests here...
} else if (argument === 'session') {
  // Run `session` specific tests here...
}
```

Note, we're using `process.argv[2].split(/:/).pop();` to extract either `user` or `session` from the array item positioned at index two, whose initial value will be either `e2etest:user` or `e2etest:session` respectively.

---

**Gruntfile**

Your `createSpec.js` file is now somewhat dependent on the grunt task named `e2etest` being invoked correctly. For example, if a user were to run `grunt e2etest` without providing the arguments then `createSpec.js` is not going to do much.

To enforce the correct usage of the `e2etest` task (i.e. it must be run using either `grunt e2etest:user` or `grunt e2etest:session`), you could change your task in your `Gruntfile` as follows:

```js
grunt.registerTask('e2etest', function(scope) {
  if (!scope || !(scope === 'user' || scope === 'session')) {
    grunt.warn(`Must be invoked with: ${this.name}:user or ${this.name}:session`);
  }
  grunt.task.run('mochaTest');
});
```

The gist above initially checks that an argument has been provided and is either `user` or `session`. If the argument is incorrect or missing then [grunt.warn](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.fail) is utilized to warn the user.

If your version of nodejs does not support [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) then use `grunt.warn` as follows instead:

```
grunt.warn('Must be invoked with: ' + this.name + ':user or ' + this.name + ':session');
```

---

**Additional comment**

The code/gist shown in the **createSpec.js** section above will work if your use-case is exactly as you mention in your question. I.e. you invoke via the commandline using `grunt e2etest:user` or `grunt e2etest:session`. However, if that changes and you cannot guarantee that `e2etest:user` or `e2etest:session` will be exactly positioned at index two of the `process.argv` array, then you may need to do the following at the top of `createSpec.js` instead:

```js
// Return the value in the array which starts with
// `e2etest` then extract the string after the colon `:`
const argument = process.argv.filter(arg => {
  return arg.match(/^e2etest:.*/);
}).toString().split(':').pop();

if (argument === 'user') {
  // Run `user` specific tests here...
} else if (argument === 'session') {
  // Run `session` specific tests here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3060) for detail, and I think the solution you need here is:

```sh
node <node flags here> node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha <mocha arguments here>
```